# She's off the telephone

Tags: tense

She's off the telephone.

Is this sentence "Past Simple tense" or "Present Perfect tense"?

Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple present tense.

The verb is " 's "  which is contracted from "is"

"on the telephone" is a prepositional phrase that tells us about her.

Comment: Thank you, James

Comment: Is it possible to write this sentence another way? Which is correct: 1- She hung up the telephone. 2- She have hanged up the telephone.

Comment: There are lots of ways to describe the picture: She has finished the call.  She has hung up. The call is over.  She isn't on the phone.   You can also describe what happened just before the picture:  She hung up.  She ended the call.  But never  "She have..." always "She has ..."

Comment: Thank you, James